# How to generate these colours in ios UIColor class?

Tags: objective-c, uicolor

I want to use some of these colours as my background color in iOS project but can't figure it out.

Here is the link

http://ios7colors.com

Comment: "When you hover over a block the HEX color codes will show." Or, if it's not that, what can't you figure out?

Comment: It would help if you posted some code to go along with the problem and elaborated on where exactly you are having difficulties... At this point, the question is vague and could mean anything from how to set the background value to how to make a gradient through UIColor

Comment: sorry, that was my first question on stackoverflow. i will be more specific. At the moment i am using "self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor]"  for  views background. on http://ios7colors.com/ i have found some beatiful colours but it has two HEX colour. i can't figure how to apply these HEX colour as view background UIColor.

Comment: You should have an app on your mac called "Digital Color Meter". You can hover over the colors you like from the web site, and it will give you the values in red green blue format.

Comment: ".. but it has two HEX color" -- these are gradients. Setting a single background color won't work to get those.

Comment: @GetMe4GetMe for converting RGB Hex values to UIColor you can use this useful library https://github.com/burhanuddin353/TFTColor

Answer (score 0):

UIColor accepts colors as ranges of RGB values from 0...1.

The numbers in the hex format in the example are hexadecimal values (0x00...0xFF) RGB packed next to each other. You need to convert them. So for example in Swift:

```
// #34AADC

let color = UIColor(
      red: CGFloat(0x34)/CGFloat(255), 
      green: CGFloat(0xAA)/CGFloat(255), 
      blue: CGFloat(0xDC)/CGFloat(255), alpha: 1)
```

In Objective C you would do the same thing but use

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red
                    green:(CGFloat)green
                     blue:(CGFloat)blue
                    alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

again, you need to convert the values from 0-FF hex to 0-1 decimal floating point.

Something like this (untested) should work:

```
// #34AADC
self.view.backgroundColor = 
    [UIColor colorWithRed: 0x34/255.0 green:0xAA/255.0 blue:0xDC/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Comment: sorry, that was my first question on stackoverflow. i will be more specific. At the moment i am using "self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor]"  for  views background. on http://ios7colors.com/ i have found some beatiful colours but it has two HEX colour. i can't figure how to apply these HEX colour as view background UIColor.   (Objective C)

Comment: Ah, you are in Objective C and my example is swift. Instead of my code use + (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red
                    green:(CGFloat)green
                     blue:(CGFloat)blue
                    alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
You need to convert the hex values to range 0-1 as I mentioned above.